# What is $\lim\limits_{n \to 0} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{n} x^n$?

Tags: calculus, limits

A limit that I find rather intriguing is $\lim\limits_{n \to 0} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{n} x^n$. Following the usual rules for differentiation of polynomials, this would be  $\lim\limits_{n \to 0} \frac {nx^{n-1}}{n} = x^{-1}$. It seems unlikely that this is actually the limit because the derivative of $ln(x)$ is $1/x$. Is there a way to prove what this actually is?

Comment: Actually, we have $\lim_{n\to0}\frac{x^n-1}{n}=\log x$.

Comment: " It seems unlikely that this is actually the derivative"  It seems unlikely the is actually the derivative of what?  Are you assuming $\lim \frac {df}{dx} = \frac {d\lim f}{dx}$?  When would that be justified do you think?  And  Why wouldn't you expect $\lim \frac 1n x^n = \ln x$?

Comment: The derivative of what?  I don't understand your question $\lim \frac d{dx}\frac 1n x^n = \lim x^{n-1} = x^{-1}$ unqestionably and $\frac {d\ln x}{dx} = x^{-1}$ unquestionably and ..... what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mistake in your reasoning. What you may find confusing is that you started from something that seems to have nothing to do with $\ln(x)$. Except in the process you took $n$ to tend to $0$ at some point. So to be fair let's see what happens when you try to do that *before* taking the derivative. You will see that it doesn't really make sense, it tends to infinity everywhere. Except look closely at the shape of the curve: it tends to look more and more like $\ln(x)$, escaping up to infinity!

Now the derivative doesn't care about vertical translations: if you replace $f_n(x)$ by $f_n(x)-f_n(1)$, it will not tend to infinity any more, it will have the same derivative, and it *will* tend to $\ln(x)$.

See this output by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E0.001%2F0.001+for+x+from+0+to+10):

[image]

Comment: Downvote? Really?

Answer (score 1):

The function $x^t$ for arbitrary real $t$ is only defined for $x>0$ as
$$
x^t=\exp(t\log x)
$$
(natural logarithm). Then, by the chain rule,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}x^t=\exp(t\log x)\cdot\frac{t}{x}=t
\exp(t\log x-\log x)=\exp((t-1)\log x)=tx^{t-1}
$$
Thus your limit is indeed
$$
\lim_{t\to0}x^{t-1}=\lim_{t\to0}\exp((t-1)\log x)=x^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually,
that is true.

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{n \to 0}\dfrac{x^n-1}{n}
&=\lim_{n \to 0}\dfrac{e^{n\ln x}-1}{n}\\
&=\lim_{n \to 0}\dfrac{1+n\ln x+O(n^2)-1}{n}\\
&=\lim_{n \to 0}\ln x + O(n)\\
&=\ln x\\
\end{array}
$